# SQL Joining many-to-many key relationship tables makes it hard to find the distinct sum

Tags: sql

This question has been asked in certain ways before, however I was unable to find a solution when it comes to finding a correct way to sum the duplicated values.

Problem: I have three tables, and I want to get to Table D.[Tables available/desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQnBp.png)

The problem I run into is illustrated here [sample data and how it screws up my goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FblI.png)

Does anyone know a way to do this? Of course, I've simplified the tables from the actual ones, as they have 100+ columns

Comment: Look into SUM and GROUP BY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're aware the replicated values from tableA are causing your issue.

To resolve, SUM() the values in table C/B grouping by the join criteria to A.

Put another way, sum the values before the join so you don't have to deal with tableA replicated values thus creating a 1:1 before the join occurs; eliminating the replicated values of A.

```
SELECT A.IID, A.TotalTime+coalesce(sub.total,0) as TotalTime
FROM tableA A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT C.IID, sum(B.totalTime) Total 
           FROM tableC C
           INNER JOIN tableB  B
              on C.CID = B.CID
           GROUP BY C.IID) sub
 on A.IID= sub.IID
```

Since the inline view will result in 1 record per IID and we join on IID, then it becomes a 1:1 relationship and the A records don't get Duplicated/replicated for each value in the B/C tables.

I used a left join as I didn't know if for all records in A if there were associated records in B/C.  I assumed you would always want A even if no such other records existed.

Comment: Oh wow yeah this is the solution. Grouping and summing by CID initially ensures a 1-to-1 or 1-to-0 between IID and CID. Thanks so much!